# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel crash on multithread environment

Tags: kernel, 22.04, crash

```
#21 0x00007fddd3c42b43 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_create.c:442
#22 0x00007fddd3cd4a00 in clone3 () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone3.S:81
(gdb) info reg
rax            0xfffffffffffffffc  -4
rbx            0x0                 0
rcx            0x7fddd3c3f197      140590717333911
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x189               393
rdi            0x7fddcc054794      140590587398036
rbp            0x7fddcc054768      0x7fddcc054768
rsp            0x7fddd46b45e0      0x7fddd46b45e0
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0xffffffff          4294967295
r10            0x7fddd46b4820      140590728300576
r11            0x246               582
r12            0x0                 0
r13            0x0                 0
r14            0x7fddcc054794      140590587398036
r15            0x7                 7
rip            0x7fddd3c3f197      0x7fddd3c3f197 <__GI___futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable64+231>
eflags         0x246               [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs 

        0x0                 0
```

(gdb) info threads

```
  Id   Target Id                          Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7fddd46b5640 (LWP 345144) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd46b4820, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc054794) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  2    Thread 0x7fddd5eff640 (LWP 345124) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd5efeb80, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc004354) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  3    Thread 0x7fddd4e3f640 (LWP 345127) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-872292256, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd4e3ecc0,
    op=393, expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddc4001084) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  4    Thread 0x7fddd13ff640 (LWP 345120) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd13fed80, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddd701be08 <spq+104>) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  5    Thread 0x7fddd4b5e640 (LWP 345129) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-742119344, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd4b5dcb0,
    op=393, expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc116d90) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  6    Thread 0x7fddd75f3c40 (LWP 345119) 0x00007fddd3cc97ed in __GI___select (nfds=4, readfds=0x7ffe783541f0, writefds=0x0,
    exceptfds=0x0, timeout=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c:69
  7    Thread 0x7fddd4694640 (LWP 345145) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x0, op=393, expected=0,
    futex_word=0x7fddd569a358 <rmi_API+472>) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  8    Thread 0x7fddd673f640 (LWP 345123) 0x00007fddd3cc6d7f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fddc0000d60, nfds=2, timeout=-1)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  9    Thread 0x7fddd4b7f640 (LWP 345128) 0x00007fddd3cc6d7f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fddd4b7e2c8, nfds=1, timeout=-1)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  10   Thread 0x7fddd56bf640 (LWP 345126) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x0, op=393, expected=0,
    futex_word=0x7fddd0a3cf10 <dispatch_lock+80>) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  11   Thread 0x7fddd4673640 (LWP 345146) __GI___libc_read (nbytes=4, buf=0x7fddd4672dd0, fd=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
  12   Thread 0x7fddd5abf640 (LWP 345125) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x0, op=393, expected=0,
    futex_word=0x7fddd569a434 <rmi_API+692>) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  13   Thread 0x7fddd4718640 (LWP 345141) 0x00007fddd3c93868 in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0,
    req=0x7fddd4717cb0, rem=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
  14   Thread 0x7fddd4b3d640 (LWP 345130) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd4b3ccc0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc0112c0) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  15   Thread 0x7fddd47ff640 (LWP 345134) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd47fece0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc07fc30) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  16   Thread 0x7fddd6c7f640 (LWP 345122) futex_wait (private=0, expected=20, futex_word=0x7fddd6c7df00)
    at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:146
  17   Thread 0x7fddd46d6640 (LWP 345143) 0x00007fddd3cc6d7f in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fddd46d5e18, nfds=1, timeout=-1)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
  18   Thread 0x7fddd47bd640 (LWP 345136) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd47bcce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc07eee0) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  19   Thread 0x7fddd477b640 (LWP 345138) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd477ace0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc07f3e0) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
  20   Thread 0x7fddd4afb640 (LWP 345132) 0x00007fddd3c3f972 in __GI___nptl_setxid_sighandler (sig=33, si=0x7fddcc0d1f70,
    ctx=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/nptl_setxid.c:82
  21   Thread 0x7fddd4739640 (LWP 345140) __GI___nptl_setxid_sighandler (sig=33, si=0x7fddcc1a4e70, ctx=<optimized out>)
    at ./nptl/nptl_setxid.c:72
  22   Thread 0x7fddd475a640 (LWP 345139) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd4759ce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc0fa5a0) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  23   Thread 0x7fddd4b1c640 (LWP 345131) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd4b1bce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc0819e0) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  24   Thread 0x7fddd47de640 (LWP 345135) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd47ddce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc07f710) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  25   Thread 0x7fddd4ada640 (LWP 345133) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=0, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd4ad9ce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc07fa30) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  26   Thread 0x7fddd479c640 (LWP 345137) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd479bce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc07f160) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
  27   Thread 0x7fddd46f7640 (LWP 345142) __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 (private=-1, cancel=true, abstime=0x7fddd46f6ce0, op=393,
    expected=0, futex_word=0x7fddcc080930) at ./nptl/futex-internal.c:57
```

Comment: I have added code tags to your question to make it more easy to read. Could you please add a few more details about this crash: when it happens, is it reproducible, have you made any changes to your system etc etc ?

Comment: Hi @ArturMeinild the ubuntu 22.04 we are facing issue in ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 are working fine with my app

Comment: Hi @andrew.46 the app dumps core while adding Application resources at __futex_abstimed_wait_common64 , yes this is reproducible  ,we didnt made any change at system level , and same build is working fine for Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04